# Help applying Classes as fields

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is to implement a constructor of an Object which is a class.
I have defined the class in the fields of the class; but because it is a class I dont know how to initialize it.

here is my class, and the fields.

```
public class Player
{
// Instance variables.
//Weapon is a class.        
//The max health starts at 30 health points.

  private String myPlayerName;
  private Weapon myWeapon;
  private int myCurrentHealth;
  private int myMaxHealth;
  private int myNumPotions;

/**
 * Constructor initializing class Player
 * Parameters of the player should be:
 * player name, players initial health, the players weapon.
 */
  public Player(String myPlayer, int initialHealth, Weapon currentWeapon) {
      myPlayerName = myPlayer;
      myWeapon = new Weapon();
      myMaxHealth = 30; 
      initialHealth = myMaxHealth;
      myCurrentHealth = initialHealth;
      myNumPotions = 0;       
}
```

There is something going wrong here, Im not sure what? Can anyone help me construct the currentWeapon parameter?

Comment: I am learning in BlueJ;
so when I am creating a new Player class; the parameters are asking for ("name", int, //something here, this is what I am unsure of//)

Comment: you need to pass in an 'instance' of a Weapon.  So something like new Weapon as I said in my answer.

Comment: If you did not figure this out yet or get an acceptable answer yet, you might want to post your `Weapon` class.  Then someone can show you how to construct a `Player`.

Comment: Just pointing this out: the value of `initialHealth` is never used. There's no real problem if you want to ignore it 'til you're prepared to implement it later, and keep the argument, but you might as well ignore it properly and skip all mention of it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be this? Why are you constructing a new Weapon object instead of assigning the one passed in the constructor argument?

```
this.myWeapon = currentWeapon;
```

**Update**

Construct the Player class this way:-

```
Player player = new Player("Tom", 10, new Weapon(10,20));
```

Comment: I did have this code, but the problem is that when I am constructing the Player object, the parameters are ("blah", "int", *unsure of what to construct here*)

Comment: @Alex Jones - Do this - `new Player("Tom", 10, new Weapon());` to construct a Player object. However, I am not sure if there are additional parameters on the Weapon object that you may need to set. In that case we will have to it little differently. Add the code for the Weapon class.

Comment: When a type new Weapon() I get an error in BlueJ saying "cannot find constructor Weapon"
I have edited in the code for the Weapon class..

Comment: @Alex Jones - Because you do not have a constructor like that. Change it to this line - `new Player("Tom", 10, new Weapon(10,20));` . Is this homework?

Comment: That worked now!
So, just to make sure I understand the concept; 
when I create a class which is using an object from another class, I must include parameters from the class I am constructing from?
*yes this is homework*

Comment: @Alex Jones - No you have to use the constructors that class makes available to you. It only has a constructor defined of type Weapon(int,int) so you must invoke it by passing 2 integer arguments `new Weapon(10,20)`. If the class also provided a no argument constructor (usually called a default constructor) then we could do `new Weapon()`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  Your constructor takes in a instance of a Weapon called currentWeapon but you then assign myWeapon to a new instance of Weapon and do not use your currentWeapon that was given to you.

When you construct a Player you should be doing something like:

```
new Player('blah', 100, new Weapon());
```

In your Player constructor you should then have the line:

```
myWeapon = currentWeapon;
```

Comment: When I am creating a new Player object, it asks me for a (String, int, new Weapon()).
I am learning through BlueJ, so I am unsure of how to represent a parameter which is an object type.

Comment: Honestly, stop using BlueJ. Get a real IDE like Eclipse, or an editor like vim or TextEdit. Then, you can do all of your initialization in code, instead of through a clunky, nonsensical GUI.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
myWeapon = currentWeapon;
```

or for more cleary:

```
this.myWeapon = currentWwapon;
```

it's simple because in OOP, namely C#, Java... object are **references**, so you don't have to worry.
for more specific, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) out !

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply;
I have added this code to my Player object, however I am learning on BlueJ. So when I create a new Player object, it is asking me for the parameters I have specified which is ("name", int, Weapon)
I am not sure how I am supposed to define a Weapon, as it is an object reference, not an int or string..